# How many internal links does Googlebot care about per page?

Tags: html, links, google-index

I read somewhere something like this:

> Penguin (Google algorithm) indexes (cares/reviews) only the first 5 internal links in the DOM from the top.

I that true?

---

You know, I have a "related posts box" at the bottom of the page for each post single page. Also I have some other links in the upper of that related posts, like top users in the week (which are links), FAQ (which are the links of 10 most asked questions).

Now I want to know, should I change the place of "popular" question in the HTML structure and bring them upper than other links to make Penguin investigate them or Penguin itself can understand those links "top users, FAQ" are constant (at least in the week) and should care about the bottom box which is for related posts? I want the related posts get indexed.

Comment: Penguin is a several old web spam fighting algorithm.   Unless you think your site were penalized by Penguin, I don't see how its limits on internal links per page would really matter to you.   Google certainly looks at many more links than five in normal cases.   What makes you think that Penguin is important to your site?

Comment: I've also never heard that Googlebot ever limits itself to five links per page in any circumstance.   Where did you hear that?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I just hear that from our company SEO expert .. however he himself wasn't that much sure .. anyway apparently that theory is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Yoast there is no limit for internal links, and the main rule of thumb is to just make sure they are relevant to the user:

> As long as your links are useful for your users, it’s okay. There used to be a rule of no more than 100 links on a page in the Google Webmaster Guidelines, they’ve removed that rule though. 100 links might seem like a lot if your site is a content site. But if you look at very long Wikipedia articles, they might have 300-400 URLs in there, linking to other articles and all those links are useful. So, if your links are useful like that, by all means, have them on the page.
>
> *[Ask Yoast - How many (internal) links on a page?](https://yoast.com/ask-yoast-internal-links/)*

Personally I have seen no issue having more than 5 internal links on my pages, and Google always indexes all of them even if they are linked from a single large (20 items-ish) "list" page. So whoever you learned the rule of "only 5 internal links" from must have been mistaken.